# Confused about O(n) and O(1)

Tags: time-complexity

```
int n = 1000;
int cnt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   cnt++;
```

Is the above code O(n) or O(1)? If I run the above code many times, it still iterates 1000 times. I'm really confused. I assumed it's O(1), but I'm not sure about it. Could anyone verify this?

Comment: For the notation $O(n)$ to be meaningful, there needs to be a *parameter* $n$.

Comment: We need more context, but in general, n refers to the size of the input. If you have a for loop in your code that is always going to iterate c times independently of the size of the input, even if that c is huge, that piece of code would be constant.

Comment: Imagine replacing `n` with `m` in the code. Would you still have the same confusion?

Comment: It is both $O(n)$ and $O(1)$ since $n$ is a constant. :)